# Reading RTF document page by page using C#

Tags: c#

I have a RTF file with 15 pages. I wanted to read it page by page using c#. I am using VS2015. I tried using rich text Box following the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/cc488002(v=vs.120)

This gives me the entire document as plain text, but  not the page number.
I am trying to extract certain words with their corresponding page numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to find a different solution.  RichText documents are simply text.  There is no such thing as *pages* in RichText because.. what size is the piece of paper?